# Smooth 4D (3D + color) plot from discrete points

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, interpolation

I have a file containing isosurface $\{x,y,z,F\}$ data (around 9000 points). My goal is to generate a **smooth** (NOT a discrete set of points!) colored surface using `ListContourPlot3D`, i.e., something like this:

[image]

More specifically, the surface I am trying to plot is closed.

This what I am getting if I plot *x,y,z*:

[image: surface]

Now, I want to add color on top, i.e., I want different regions of the surface to be colored differently depending *F*.

I am using  `ListContourPlot3D`, because according to the description this what I need:

> `ListContourPlot3D` linearly interpolates values to give smooth contours

Any hints? So far all my attempts have been unsuccessful.

This is what I am getting with `ListContourPlot3D[data]`:

[image]

**EDIT:** attached the file.

[file](http://www.filedropper.com/furan-ks)

I want to plot col. 1(x): col.2(y): col.3(z) col4(color)

Comment: ListContourPlot3D and ListDensityPlot?

Comment: sorry, corrected the typo

Comment: You should post a minimum (non)working example describing the problems you are having. It is not a good practice to post links to files located in Nowhere, Kansas. Plus, there are tons of Qs on how to plot 4D data in *Mathematica*. Also look up [`ListInterpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListInterpolation.html)

Comment: I don't agree the question it trivial though. Almost all questions deal with visualizing data for a given *function*, whereas in my case a nice trick of how interpolate 4D data is needed.

Comment: Looks like you need ListPlot3D, not ListContourPlot3D.  The one you show is not a contour plot or an isosurface plot.  If you upload your data somewhere, someone will surely show you how to do it (including the colouring).

Comment: The file is uploaded (at the bottom)

Comment: It would be good to change the title of this to asking about your actual problem instead of complaining that a a function not meant for the purpose you're trying to use it for "does NOT work".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`ListContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListContourPlot3D.html) does work as intended.  Please check its documentation on what it is supposed to do.  To make this kind of plot you need [`ListSurfacePlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListSurfacePlot3D.html).

```
data = Import["~/Downloads/furan-ks.sdat", "Table"];

nf = Nearest[data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]] -> Rescale[data[[All, 4]]]]

colfun = ColorData["Rainbow"]@First@nf[{#1,#2,#3}]&

ListSurfacePlot3D[
 data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]],
 BoxRatios -> Automatic,
 ColorFunction -> colfun,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False
 ]
```

[image]

You can experiment with the `MaxPlotPoints` option (e.g. set it to 20) to get the optimal surface fitting to your points.   A too tight fit will be noisy, a too loose one will look chunky.

The tricky bit here was converting the colour data into a format usable with `ListSurfacePlot3D`.  This is a non-trivial step.  I used [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Nearest.html) to create a function (named `nf`) that takes a 3D coordinate and returns the colour value of the closest point from the dataset.   Then I converted this value to an actual colour (i.e. an [`RGBColor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RGBColor.html) object) using the function `colfun`.

Comment: I think you missed the bit where you get from `nf` to `colfun`

Comment: @Simon Thanks, fixed!

Comment: @Szabolcs - what does `colfun` actually color? Height? A kind of curvature ? Density of sampling points ?

Comment: @eldo The original dataset has 4 relevant columns.  The first 3 are x,y,z coordinates of a point and the 4th is a number that we use for colouring this point.  Because of how Mathematica's `ColorFunction`s work, the colour function needs to be able to assign a colour to *any* point in 3D, not just the points in the dataset.  The function `nf` takes any 3D point, and finds the point in the dataset that is closest to it.  Then it returns the number (4th column) corresponding to this point.  What colfun does is just convert this number to an `RGBColor` object, nothing more.

Comment: @eldo So the value used for colouring comes from the dataset directly.

Comment: @Szabolcs - Understood, thank you very much :)

Comment: @eldo I guess a different type of interpolation (instead of Nearest) might have worked as well for defining the colour function.  I wasn't sure how e.g. linear interpolation would behave with this data though, so I didn't use it.  All the points are on a surface, so I was worried that 3D interpolation might fail (e.g. that because of how the underlying mesh might be generated, far-away datapoints would influence the colour in some places).  But maybe it works well.

Comment: @Szabolcs Is there a simple way (a predefined option or something) of how to add a color bar to the above plot? I didn't find anything relevant

Comment: @molkee In version 9, if the plot is stored in `plot`, something like `Legended[plot, 
 BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {Min[data[[All, 4]]], Max[data[[All, 4]]]}}]]` should do it.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks a lot! it worked out well

Answer (score 2):

Using @Szabolcs's `colfun` with `ListContourPlot3D` and `ListSurfacePlot3D` give similar images:

```
opts = {BoxRatios -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> colfun, 
        Lighting -> "Neutral", ColorFunctionScaling -> False,   ImageSize -> 400};

Row[{ListContourPlot3D[data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], opts, Contours -> {0}],
     ListSurfacePlot3D[data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], opts]}]
```

[image]

Comment: how do I add a colorbar for a plot generated with any of these methods? Setting `PlotLegends` to `Automatic` does not help

Comment: @molkee, does `PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 1}}]` give what you expect?

Comment: yes, it does. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`ListContourPlot3D` has a VERY nasty default option; it joins the points creating a surface, not discrete 3D points and this feature cannot be removed. In order to deal with this we have to come up with a radical solution like the following:

First of all, let's read the data file

```
data = ReadList["data.out", Number, RecordLists -> True];
```

I suppose that the fourth column corresponds to the value of an index so, let's find out the minimum and the maximum values of that index in our sample data file

```
datat = Table[data[[i, 4]], {i, 1, Length[data]}];
min = Min[datat];
max = Max[datat];
Print["min = ", min]
Print["max = ", max]
```

Now let's paint the 3D points with colors according to the values of the index

```
valrange = {min, max};
data[[All, 4]] = Rescale[data[[All, 4]], valrange];
colfunc[x_, cf_] := ColorData[cf][1 - x[[4]]];
```

and then plot them

```
S0 = Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.004], Point[#[[1 ;; 3]], VertexColors -> colfunc[#, "Rainbow"]] & /@ data}]
```

If we like we can also create a custom-made colorbar

```
Clear[colorbar]
colorbar[{min_, max_}, colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 150] := 
DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, min, max}, AspectRatio -> 10, 
PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{None, "index"}, {None, None}}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 17], 
FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 15, Plain], 
ColorFunction -> colorFunction]
```

and combine the colorbar with the previous 3D plot

```
With[{opts = {ImageSize -> {Automatic, 600}}, cf = "Rainbow"}, 
Row[{Show[{S0}, Axes -> True, 
AxesStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"],
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, opts], 
Show[colorbar[valrange, ColorData[cf][1 - #] &], 
ImagePadding -> {{20, 60}, {55, 25}}, opts]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. But how do I turn the last graph into smooth UNIFORM (no discrete 3D points) colored surface? Is it possible?

Comment: @molkee I can't think of anything right now. My approach works very good when you want to visualize 3D points with colors. Now join them (why you want to do that?!) is another story. My opinion is that if there is a way to join them creating a colored surface the output will not be as smooth and uniform you expect; you should expect a lot of rough edges.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyways. I appreciate it. I guess simple increase in the point mark size will do the job. you are right, the surface wouldn't be perfect, but there must be some tricks of how to smoothen it using interpolation. A number of points is enough to get a nice surface

Comment: @molkee If you really think my answer was useful to you, don't forget to vote it!

Comment: It was! by the way, is there a simpler way of how add a color bar to a 3D plot (say, `ListContourPlot3D` or `ListSurfacePlot`)? This cannot be done using `PlotLegends`