# ListContourPlot3D blank box?

Tags: plotting

I have a (long) list of {x,y,z,f} values generated using a finite element software package.  I've tried using

```
ListContourPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> All, Contours -> {0}]
```

to visualize the data set but what it generates is an empty box ranging from {-1,1} in all directions.

It sounds similar to this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497517/mathematica-listcontourplot3d but the solution provided only works for discrete data generated from a table construct; my data is already discrete.

I can visualize parts of the data using:

```
ListPlot3D[{#[[1]],#[[2]],#[[4]]}&/@data]
```

but I lose a critical part of the data when I do that.

I've also tried applying a solution similar to this: [Smooth 4D (3D + color) plot from discrete points](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50501/smooth-4d-3d-color-plot-from-discrete-points) but I lose the ability to (easily?) control the color function to stay constant between multiple data sets, ie. I do not want the color function to auto range with the current data set, I would like to be able to set the color function range between the maximum and minimum of largest data set as to track the changes over all of the data sets.

I've included a sample section of the data below which gives the general overview of the data but has been truncated from the original data set.

The output image (isn't this) but should look something like this: [image: this]

```
data={{82.1986, 90.1101, -50.5433, -0.023},
{82.1986, 13.8898, -50.5431, -0.023},
{148.544, 13.8945, -17.7456, -0.00807},
{148.543, 90.1056, -17.7443, -0.00803},
{15.8543,  90.1056, -17.7437, -0.00803},
{15.8543, 13.8944, -17.7438, -0.00804},
{82.1986, 85.028, -50.5282, -0.0234},
{82.1986, 79.9457, -50.5423, -0.0232},
{82.1986, 74.8638, -50.5669, -0.023},
{82.1986, 69.7824, -50.5912, -0.0227},
{82.1986, 64.7014, -50.6104, -0.0225},
{82.1986, 59.6207, -50.623, -0.0223},
{82.1986, 54.5402, -50.6291, -0.0223},
{82.1986, 49.4597, -50.6291, -0.0223},
{82.1986, 44.3792, -50.6229, -0.0223},
{82.1986, 39.2985, -50.6103, -0.0225},
{82.1986, 34.2175, -50.5911, -0.0227},
{82.1986, 29.1361, -50.5667, -0.023},
{82.1986, 24.0542, -50.5421, -0.0232},
{82.1986, 18.9719, -50.528, -0.0234},
{87.2701, 13.8899, -50.3669, -0.0229},
{92.3173, 13.8902, -49.8408, -0.0227},
{97.3169, 13.8908, -48.9711, -0.0223},
{102.247, 13.8915, -47.7676, -0.0217},
{107.088, 13.8922, -46.2437, -0.021},
{111.823, 13.893, -44.4156, -0.0201},
{116.438, 13.8937, -42.3021, -0.0191},
{120.922, 13.8943, -39.9237, -0.018},
{125.27, 13.8947, -37.3023, -0.0168},
{129.477, 13.895, -34.4607, -0.0155},
{133.545, 13.895, -31.4219, -0.0142},
{137.476, 13.8949, -28.2086, -0.0127},
{141.28, 13.8947, -24.8436, -0.0112},
{144.965, 13.8945, -21.3488, -0.00958},
{148.521, 18.975, -17.7192, -0.00821},
{148.511, 24.0559, -17.7071, -0.00822},
{148.509, 29.1369, -17.704, -0.00818},
{148.511, 34.2178, -17.7058, -0.00812},
{148.515, 39.2986, -17.7094, -0.00804},
{148.519, 44.3792, -17.7129, -0.00801},
{148.52, 49.4598, -17.7149, -0.00799},
{148.52, 54.5403, -17.7148, -0.00799},
{148.518, 59.6208, -17.7127, -0.00801},
{148.515, 64.7015, -17.7091, -0.00805},
{148.511, 69.7822, -17.7051, -0.0081},
{148.508, 74.8632, -17.7031, -0.00816},
{148.51, 79.9442, -17.7059, -0.00818},
{148.52, 85.0251, -17.7179, -0.00816},
{144.964, 90.1055, -21.3481, -0.00961},
{141.279, 90.1053, -24.8432, -0.0112}}
```

Comment: Also, the first row of your data has 4 elements, whereas the rest has three. You should start from there and use the correct command.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the data into Notepad++ to add the 4 spaces for formatting and I messed it up and made it look like it has 3 elements whereas it should have 4 elements throughout.

Answer (score 1):

The first and last row of `data` contain a fourth element. Eliminating this we get

Use a specific contour:

```
ListContourPlot3D[data,
 Contours -> {0},
 Mesh -> None,
 Lighting -> "Neutral",
 ContourStyle -> Texture[ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "WhiteMarble"}]]]
```

[image]

Use five equally spaced contours:

```
ListContourPlot3D[data,
 Contours -> 5,
 ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5],
 Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering the question, unfortunately the data I copied in was poorly formatted so you answered a question which doesn't help me.  Sorry!

Comment: @AndrewStewart You are welcome. Things like this happen :)