# What is the best way to visualize points in 4d? Each point has coordinates (x1,x2,x3,x4)

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

What is the best way to visualize points in 4d? Each point has coordinates (x1,x2,x3,x4). In fact these points are nodes of a quadratic mesh on a sphere in 4 dimensions. An analogy in 3d, these points will be the intersections of all longitudes and latitudes.

Comment: Have you seen these Q&A?: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=4D

Comment: Related: [19575](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19575/what-are-the-possible-ways-of-visualizing-a-4d-function-in-mathematica); [20023](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20023/plot-4d-data-with-color-as-4th-dimension); [32844](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32844/need-4d-plot-3d-color-for-function); [50501](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50501/smooth-4d-3d-color-plot-from-discrete-points).

Comment: Yes I saw all of these.. But none helps me seeing kind of points or intersection of lines. As I mensioned above in 3d case the graph will look just like the earth with longitude and latitude lines

Comment: The "best" way is in the eye of the beholder and also depends on your objective (and not just the data available).  Can you specify what features you want to highlight in such a figure (or series of figures)?  Certainly all possible pairwise plots is a standard technique (6 pairwise plots in this case).  Also there are the four 3D plots.  You could make the display interactive by choosing subsets of one of the variables and show the corresponding points of the remaining variables in a 3D plot.

Comment: @JimBaldwin. Here is exactly what I want to get : [3-sphere visualizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:3-sphere)

Comment: Thanks.  The figures on that link are of functions rather than points (as you mention in your question) so I still think you need to be more specific and relate the question to *Mathematica*.