# Create smooth colour map from given array for ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting, color, python

I am trying to find the *Mathematica* equivalent for Python Matplotlib's `cmap`  option, to be used with `ListPlot3D[]`.

Here is the situation. I want to supply `(N,1)`-sized arrays for the position `x,y,z`, and then an extra `(N,1)`-sized array `clr` that gets mapped onto some colour map that colours the different points. In Python, such data can be simply plotted using a scatter plot, and then coloured using the existing `cmap` option. For example, here is such a scatter plot coloured using a `cmap` acting on the array `clr`:

[image: plotly plot]

To get an interpolated, smooth version of the data, I prefer to plot it in Mathematica using `ListPlot3D[]`. For example, the following, created using a default `z`-based colour map: [image: Mathematica plot]

But I cannot figure out the equivalent of a custom `cmap` based on the array `clr`. Of course, I would like the colours to be interpolated smoothly as well. Is this possible?

Comment: There's an extensive list [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) of the colormaps supported by matplotlib, but I can't seem to find the colormap you used in there. Can you check your code and see what colormap (maybe the default?) was used?

Comment: @J.M. Indeed, it is the default BlueGreenYellow colormap.

Comment: The second plot uses that, yes. I was asking about the one you generated in matplotlib.

Comment: Ah, this is a Plotly 3d scatter plot. Not matplotlib. It uses the default Plotly colormap. See here: https://community.plot.ly/t/what-colorscales-are-available-in-plotly-and-which-are-the-default/2079/2

Comment: Well, the way you phrased it in your post was confusing. :) So, you'd like a surface produced with `ListPlot3D[]`, but colored with (apparently) the "Portland" colormap? (Also, can you maybe post (a small sample of) your data to [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)?)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found an answer to this in a separate post: [Smooth 4D (3D + color) plot from discrete points](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50501/smooth-4d-3d-color-plot-from-discrete-points)

The trick is to define a custom `ColorFunction` (not easy) as done in the link above:

```
data = Import["~/Downloads/furan-ks.sdat", "Table"];

nf = Nearest[data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]] -> Rescale[data[[All, 4]]]]

colfun = ColorData["Rainbow"]@First@nf[{#1,#2,#3}]&
```

`data` is a 4-column data array, and the definitions of `nf` and `colfun` are sufficient to paint the surface plot according to the value of the 4th column. How this works is explained in the link above.

As opposed to what is written in the above link, this custom `ColorFunction` works with both `ListSurfacePlot3D` and `ListPlot3D` (and other similar 3D functions, I presume). You just need to add the options `ColorFunction -> colfun, ColorFunctionScaling -> False`.

In the end, my plot looks as follows:

[image: colored plot]

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP was unable/unwilling to provide data, I'm coming up with my own:

```
states = Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {#, "UnitedStates"}] & /@
         CountryData["UnitedStates", "Regions"];

pos = Reverse[First[EntityValue[#, "Position"]]] & /@ states;

logPop = Log10[N[QuantityMagnitude[EntityValue[#, "Population"]]]] & /@ states;

logGSP = Log10[QuantityMagnitude[EntityValue[#, "GrossStateProduct"]]] & /@ states;
```

For the purposes of this answer, I'll use the triplet of `pos` with `logPop` as the $x$-$y$-$z$ data, and use `logGSP`as the color map. Let's plot the data first as is:

```
dat = MapThread[Append, {pos, logPop}];
ListPlot3D[dat, ViewPoint -> {-2.4, -1.3, 2.}]
```

[image: data plot]

Now, here is how to color with respect to `logGSP`: we create an interpolating function by feeding the values of `logGSP` rescaled to $[0,1]$ along with the associated $x$ and $y$ to `Interpolation[]`:

```
ifun = Interpolation[MapThread[Append, {pos, Rescale[logGSP]}]];
```

(There is a warning thrown, but it is mostly harmless here.)

From here, we can use `ifun` along with an appropriate color function. Let's borrow the one in [plotly](https://plot.ly/) used in the OP's picture:

```
portland = Blend[{RGBColor[4/85, 1/5, 131/255], RGBColor[2/51, 8/15, 62/85], 
                  RGBColor[242/255, 211/255, 56/255], RGBColor[242/255, 143/255, 56/255], 
                  RGBColor[217/255, 2/17, 2/17]}, #] &;
```

Now let's put it all together, along with `Legended[]` to provide a sense of what the colors map to:

```
rng = MinMax[logGSP];
Legended[ListPlot3D[dat, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, portland[ifun[x, y]]], 
                    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
                    PlotStyle -> Specularity[0.9, 50], PlotTheme -> None, 
                    ViewPoint -> {-2.4, -1.3, 2.}], 
         BarLegend[{portland[Rescale[#, rng]] &, rng}]]
```

[image: colorized data plot]

For comparison purposes, here is the result if one uses `Nearest[Thread[pos -> Rescale[logGSP]]]` as the coloring function:

[image: colorized data plot, take two]