# How to do ListDensityPlot using this kind of colorfunction?

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, color

I would like to plot a figure using this kind of colorfunction in Mathematica.
I opened the "Color Schemes" from the Palettes menu, but did not find a proper colorfunction.

[image]

Comment: Why not mention where you got this color gradient from? Also, have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155599)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I've extracted a long thin part of your image to get the colours. Then I use the value provided by default `ColorFunctionScaling` from 0 (blue) to 1 (red), to extract the nearest colour or clip to the colours at the endpoints:

```
(* get the image and smooth it out to reduce the banding effects *)
img = GaussianFilter[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJlC6.png"],11];

(* Take a slice of the image from top to bottom, ignoring black and white parts, then reverse *)
colours = Reverse[ImageData[ImageTake[img, {105, -185}, {100, 120}]][[All, 1]]];

(* scaled from 0 (-50) to 1 (0) *)
scale = Length[colours];
(* select the part of the list near scaled up 'v' and clip to ends if necessary *)
mycf[v_] := RGBColor@colours[[Round[Clip[v*scale, {1, Length[colours]}]]]]

DensityPlot[-x y, {x, 0, 7}, {y, 0, 7}, ColorFunction -> mycf, PlotPoints -> 40]
```

[image: colour function density plot]

Comment: Hi, flinty, thank you for your solutions. Now I just updated this post. Could you have time to  look at my new questions?

Comment: @C.E. ok.sorry I did not know this. I just post a new question.

Comment: @flinty Hi, flinty, can you help me for my new question? Thank you. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225646/listdensityplot-using-a-customized-colorfunction