# Help making 4D heatmaps using ListSurfacePlot3D on a 4D {x,y,z,v} dataset

Tags: plotting, color

I am attempting to create a color heatmap using ListSurfacePlot3D with a dataset in the format {X, Y, Z, v}, where 'v' represents the color scale.

The dataset is stored in a CSV file with four columns: 'X', 'Y', 'Z', and 'v'. Each row corresponds to a point in 3D space, identified by the positional information. My goal is to generate a surface heatmap using ListSurfacePlot3D, with colors determined by the values in the 'v' column and following the "BlueGreenYellow" color palette.

I have successfully generated the surface using the "X," "Y," and "Z" values.

```
filePath = "df_VHH_12nm_final.csv";
data = Import[filePath];
coordinates= data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]];
ListSurfacePlot3D[coordinates, Mesh -> None,
MaxPlotPoints -> 50]
```

However, I am unable to associate the colors to the surface using a color palette and the row-specific 'v' values. Any ideas?

Thank you so much for your help!

**EDIT/Solved:** I was able to follow the info found on [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50501/smooth-4d-3d-color-plot-from-discrete-points) post.

```
filePath = "df_VHH_12nm_final.csv";
data = Import[filePath]; 
nf = Nearest[data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]] -> Rescale[data[[All, 4]]]]
colfun = ColorData["AvocadoColors"]@First@nf[{#1, #2, #3}] &
ListSurfacePlot3D[data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]],
 MaxPlotPoints -> 50,
 BoxRatios -> Automatic,
 ColorFunction -> colfun,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 Axes -> False,
 Boxed -> False]
```

Comment: `data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]]` extracts the coordinates, not the colors. The colors would be `data[[All, 4]]`. And you don't show how you attempted to use the colors.

Comment: @BobHanlon
Yup, unfortunately I am extremely new to mathematica. I regularly use matplotlib and plotly.

I have tried to do stuff like this:
<pre> <code> coordinates = data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]];
    colorValues = data[[All, 4]];
    
    colorFunction = ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"];
    
    ListSurfacePlot3D[coordinates, Mesh -> None, MaxPlotPoints -> 50, 
     ColorFunction -> (colorFunction[#] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
     Axes -> True, Boxed -> False]

Comment: Probably you would get quick helpful answers if you would provide a minimal working example (including data)